# How to use HTML markups in .po translation files using <Trans id="xxx"/> (@lingui/react)

Tags: html, reactjs, po

In my React code I have:

```
<Trans id={"hello"} />
```

In .po file I have:

```
msgid "hello"
msgstr "Hello <strong> world! </strong>"
```

But translation does not work with `<strong>`. Is there a way I can make this text bold?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
<Trans id={"hello"}>
<strong>world!</strong>
</Trans>

msgid "hello"
msgstr "Hello <0> world! </0>"
```